# how to share a php/mysql application over lan?

Tags: php, mysql, lan

i have **php/mysql** application.it is running in one computer in **xampp server**. how do i share it over **LAN** so that other computers can access it.

Comment: i want details step by step instructions.

Comment: I was going to try to give you a constructive answer but "i want details step by step instructions" was a bit on the pushy side when you are asking for so much.

Comment: If you want details, you're going to have to PROVIDE details; at the moment, the only options you've left us are "Be vague" or "Guess". I went with the former, @RahulJha the latter; each is equally valid in the absence of information from your end.

Answer (score 4):

1) Figure out your IP address on the LAN (how you do this depends on the OS the XAMPP is running on, but you should certainly be able to find someone here on SO that has asked the question for your OS);

2) Disable any Firewall software you might have running; again, search SO for the specific OS/software in your environment.

3) Have users on the LAN open their web browsers to http://your.ip.address.here/

Comment: This was covered above under "disable any Firewall software"

Comment: i have windows 7 os and do i have to install XAMPP in every machine running over lan or installing in one machine is enough? suppose the folder in XAMPP is "visitors" and in localhost i'm writing "localhost/visitors" what do i write the url over lan? should it be " http://ip.address.here/localhost/visitors" or "http://ip.address.here/visitors"?

Comment: You only need XAMPP on the machine you want to behave as a web server, and it should be http://someIPaddress/visitors, assuming you set your DocumentRoot correctly

Comment: i already did that but it is showing error like new XAMPP security error in httpd-xampp.conf and error 403.

Comment: Sounds like your XAMPP is (mis)?configured to require some kind of authorization before giving out that web page. I would recommend starting a question with the specific XAMPP error message you're getting, and linking to a copy of you XAMPP configuration file(s) so that people have at least a chance of providing meaningful help.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using XAMPP then install your XAMPP in C drive.once you will do this you can access your application using your ip address through different system in lan. i implemented the same environment during my university days.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that XAMPP doesn't imply any particular OS; they provide packages for Windows, Linux, and Mac OSX.

Comment: i considered XAMPP for windows

Comment: Which, as I noted above, is a perfectly valid assumption given the evidence at hand; that comment was really just more for your own edification to point out "Hey, XAMPP does not equate to Windows." :)